# Why might I be getting an access error from an Azure WebJob using WebJobsSdk.marker file? What is this file?

Tags: azure, runtime-error, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I'm specifically trying to understand what the WebJobsSdk.marker file is for and how it is used. It is a black-box to me so it is hard to understand why there is an access problem here.

The Error:

> The process cannot access the file '...\WebJobsSdk.marker' because it
>   is being used by another process.

Any help or insight on this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The WebJobs SDK is no longer a black box, it is open source now :)

The marker file is generated [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/605f161fa1594bd61b076271287ebccb2d373f29/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Executors/JobHostContextFactory.cs#L326-L358) and it is used by Kudu to determine if the webjob is using the SDK or not.

There might be a bug in that code, maybe it is not catching all the expected exceptions. Feel free to open a bug in GitHub